# (v2.90) Gradual vertex group shrinkwrap?

Tags: shrinkwrap

On this padded-shoulder suit jacket I'm making, I use Shrinkwrap with vertex groups to tightly fit only the sleeves, since the body of the jacket has a good fit already. However, everything in the vertex group is instantly 100% fitted to the arm--is there a way to taper the fit with just the Shrinkwrap modifier? (I somewhat achieved what I wanted via Bridge Edge Loops, but I may need a better explanation of its features to use it well.)

[image]  [image]

Comment: You have better chances of getting a answers if all of the information 
is visible in this page, instead of asking users go through links 
to understand what you want to do. Please use the [edit] link at 
the bottom of your post (https://i.stack.imgur.com/lXFuK.png) and use 
the tools from this site to upload images so that they are displayed 
as part of your question. See [How to upload an image to a post?] 
(https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491)

Comment: Edited. Still dunno if the images are needed though.

Comment: You can draw weight paints with a gradient with ALT + click drag

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The influence of a *Shrinkwrap* modifier is weighted by its target vertex-group, if it has one. All the usual tools in [Weight-Painting](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/sculpt_paint/weight_paint/introduction.html) are available to  modify the vertex-weights.. blurring.. normalising..

[image]

Once a group exists, and if at least one of its vertices is selected, vertex-weights can be [set in Edit Mode](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/meshes/properties/vertex_groups/vertex_weights.html#display-weights-in-edit-mode), for more control.